# In-App Purchase Downloads never get downloaded

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, storekit

I'm having an issue where i have an in-app purchase where I want to test with my sandbox. 
The status of the in-app purchase is "Ready to Submit" and I have followed the steps to upload the pkg file to the in-app purchase.

The transaction in the sandbox works ok, but when it comes to downloading, the
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedDownloads:(NSArray *)downloads 
delegate function is being called only once. And it first goes into the block "else if (download.downloadState == SKDownloadStateActive)", and prints "Progress ... 0 .. "

Does the in-app purchase have to be "reviewed and approved" by Apple before the download will work? 
Else what could be the error?

Thanks.

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    for (SKPaymentTransaction * transaction in transactions) {
        switch (transaction.transactionState)
        {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                if (transaction.downloads) {
                    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] startDownloads:transaction.downloads];
                }
                [self completeTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                [self failedTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                if (transaction.downloads) {
                    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] startDownloads:transaction.downloads];
                }
                [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
            default:
                break;
        }
    };
}


- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedDownloads:(NSArray *)downloads;
{
    for (SKDownload *download in downloads) {

        if (download.downloadState == SKDownloadStateFinished) {
            [self processDownload:download]; // not written yet
            // now we're done
            [queue finishTransaction:download.transaction];

        } else if (download.downloadState == SKDownloadStateActive) {

            NSString *productID = download.contentIdentifier; // in app purchase identifier
            NSTimeInterval remaining = download.timeRemaining; // secs
            float progress = download.progress; // 0.0 -> 1.0
            NSLog(@"Downloading %@", productID);
            NSLog(@"progress... %f time remaining %f", progress, remaining);
            // NOT SHOWN: use the productID to notify your model of download progress...

        } else {    // waiting, paused, failed, cancelled
            NSLog(@"Warn: not handled: %d", download.downloadState);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In-App Purchase for testing does not need to be approved by Apple.  I am experiencing the same thing.  Have you found out what the problem is?

Comment: I found out the reason why paymentQueue:updatedDownloads is being called only once in my program. In the function completeTransaction, [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction] is called after I run [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] startDownloads:transaction.downloads].  'finishTransaction' should only be called if there are no transaction.downloads.

Answer (score 3):

remove this line from `updatedTransaction`

```
[self completeTransaction:transaction];
```

and insert it in

```
if (download.downloadState == SKDownloadStateFinished) {
        // now we're done
        [self completeTransaction:download.transaction];
}
```

This way `updatedDownloads` will be called with download progress.